# Fetch multiple urls then set state accordingly React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, async-await, promise.all

I'm trying to fetch multiple .png images then set my state accordingly.
I've managed to asynchronously fetch all of the urls without using Promise.all; however, the subsequent setstate function was being executed before the promises resolved. Therefore, I changed the code to include `promise.all`, but it doesn't seem that I'm using the function correctly. I'm receiving the error "undefined is not a function (near '...podexData.map...')". Does anyone know what's going on?

[image]

Comment: Please provide relevant code in post, as code instead of image.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like below

```
const reqArray = [];
podexData.map(pokemon => reqArray.push(fetch(pokemon.url)));

Promise.all(reqArray).then(allResponses => {
  allResponses.map(pokemonData => 
    dex.push(....);
  );
  this.setState({...});
  ...

})
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!!! I think I need to convert the responses to a json somehow. Normally I'd call .then(resp=>resp.json()) after a fetch call, but I don't know how to do it here. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I added the line
.then(responses => Promise.all(responses.map(r => r.json())))
and it worked perfectly!! THANK YOU :)